# Reaction mechanism (SN2 and SN1 reactions)

Tags: organic-chemistry

How to determine whether a reaction is an SN1 or SN2 reaction?
I am unable to determine whether a reaction would form a transition state or not,
I referred the NCERT textbook but didn't found anything that could clear my doubt.

Comment: I would like to suggest this book: Electron Flow in Organic Chemistry by Paul H. Scudder. Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 4):

SN1 is characterized by the possibility of formation of a stable carbocation during the reaction, whereas in the case of SN2 there cannot be formed a stable carbocation, so the most stable "intermediate" structure would be a transitional state. Stable carbocations are formed via groups with strong inductive electronic effects (+I those that repell electrons) or they can be stabilized by conjugation (the case for this one is when you have a double, triple bond or an aromatic ring directly bound to the carbon atom where the substitution takes place)
so, for example, (CH3)3C-Cl would make for an SN1 when reactiong with alcohols. Also compounds like CH2=CH-CH2-Cl.
The remaining cases, for example CH3-Cl or CH3-CH2-Cl would work via SN2, because the carbocation cannot be stabilized.
Hope that's gonna help you :)

Comment: Sn2 will form a transition state and Sn1 will form an intermediate product.